# How to resize textboxarea in MVC 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am very new to MVC and I am  trying to **automatically** resize my `textbox area` in **MVC2** which receives data from controller

I have tried

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery /1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/jquery.autoresize.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target").autoResize();
    });
</script>

  <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.QDetail, new { @id="target" }) %>
```

But it doesnt work...

Thank you All

Answer (score 1):

Try to use autoresize as mentioned below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target").autoResize();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just make sure to include the jQuery plugin: https://github.com/alexbardas/jQuery.fn.autoResize